# What is the easiest way to prevent an Exchange 2010 AD user sending email temporarily?

Tags: email, exchange

What is the easiest way to prevent an Exchange 2010 AD user sending email temporarily? We don't want their AD account disabled, but just stop them emailing anyone temporarily. What's the easiest solution?

Comment: Break their fingers?

Answer (score 3):

One of the following should work.  On the mailbox properties these are on the Mail Flow Settings tab:

1. Set the Maximum Recipients to 0 (Delivery Options properties)
2. Set Maximum Sending Message size to 0 (Message Size Restrictions properties)

Comment: +1 for the max recipients, elegang solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Transport Rules

1. Open Exchange Management console
2. Select Organisation Configuration --> Hub Transport
3. Action panel --> New Transport rule
4. Follow the wizard, in action window, select `send bounce message to sender with enhanced status code` or `silently drop the message`